# Watir: RubyInstaller DevKit Installation error

Tags: ruby, rubygems, watir

Been trying to install the Devkit in WIN XP but can't get past the 
following point Can you please help me? --code follows:

```
C:\devkit>ruby dk.rb init
[INFO] found RubyInstaller v1.9.3 at C:/Ruby193

Initialization complete! Please review and modify the auto-generated
'config.yml' file to ensure it contains the root directories to all
of the installed Rubies you want enhanced by the DevKit.

C:\devkit>ruby dk.rb install --force

**[INFO] Updating convenience notice gem override for 'C:/Ruby193'**

[INFO] Installing 'C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/devkit.rb'

------------------------------------------------------

C:\devkit>devkitvars.bat
Adding the DevKit to PATH...

C:\devkit>
C:\devkit>make --version
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for i686-pc-msys

C:\devkit>
```

My Problem is that when I try irb I am getting this error message below and I though the reason  was that gem wasn't installed

```
D:\Documents and Settings\cfoley1>irb
irb(main):001:0> require "watir"
=> true

irb(main):002:0>

irb(main):003:0* browser = Watir::Browser.new
FFI::NotFoundError: Function '_get_errno' not found in [msvcrt.dll]
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commonwatir-2.0.4/lib/watir/bro
wser.rb:89:in `eval'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/win32-process-0.7.0/lib/win32/p
rocess/functions.rb:12:in `attach_pfunc'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/win32-process-0.7.0/lib/win32/p
rocess/functions.rb:64:in `<module:Functions>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/win32-process-0.7.0/lib/win32/p
rocess/functions.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:i
n `require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:i
n `require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/win32-process-0.7.0/lib/win32/p
rocess.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:i
n `require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:i
n `require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-2.0.4/lib/watir/ie-proces
s.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:i
n `require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:i
n `require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-2.0.4/lib/watir/ie.rb:4:i
n `<top (required)>'
        from (eval):1:in `klass'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commonwatir-2.0.4/lib/watir/bro
wser.rb:89:in `eval'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commonwatir-2.0.4/lib/watir/bro
wser.rb:89:in `klass'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commonwatir-2.0.4/lib/watir/bro
wser.rb:79:in `set_options'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commonwatir-2.0.4/lib/watir/bro
wser.rb:142:in `set_sub_options'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commonwatir-2.0.4/lib/watir/bro
wser.rb:64:in `new'
        from (irb):3
        from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'irb(main):004:0>
```

Comment: What version of Watir are you trying to use? Based on your exception, it looks like you are currently using 2.0.4. Does the problem happen if you use the latest Watir version?

Comment: Yes I downloaded the latest Version from http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads and still have the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
gem uninstall win32-process -v 0.7.0
gem install win32-process -v 0.6.6
```

Thanks to everyone to point me to the right direction

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like you have installed devkit. Is there a problem?

Comment: The question shows no research or attempt at all to describe the issue. Seems is not DevKit but Watir what is not working as expected. User double posted on RubyInstaller group: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/rubyinstaller/-Jo_nt1V6Fs/discussion